# Unknown face classification using FaceNet embedding

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, svm, face-recognition

I'm trying to use a classifier to recognise faces of family members.

For now I'm using facenet embedding as input with a SVM classifier. With the limited number of faces that I have to distinguish, this gives really good results.

However I'm not quite sure what to do in order to detect an unknown face as such.

I tried training the classier on family faces as well as on a hundred more faces from the LFW database. If the prediction confidence is low enough, I say it's an unknown face.

Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another layer of authentication to the output class.
Suppose your classifier return 'xyz' as output class. You can then double check by comparing the input image and image which is in your data set. Best way will be to compare the embedding of those two image and check for threshold distance.